# Error while using javax.mail for sending a mail

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am using the following code, the code executes till message.setSubject(body1); then it doesn't throw any exception but directly stops executing the complete program. the same with  messageBodyPart.setText("Hi, Status mail"); when I tried with setSubject commented out. At least it doesn't even throw an exception. What might be the problem?

```
 String body1 = "TODAYS UPDATED FILES LIST";
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
 props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
 props.put("mail.smtp.host", Global.HOST);                 
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", Global.PORT);
 Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
 Message message = new MimeMessage(session);                                                                                                
          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EMAIL_FROM));   
          for(int i=0;i<EMAIL_TO.size();i++){

            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(EMAIL_TO.get(i)));
        } 
                    message.setSubject(body1);
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText("Hi, Status mail");
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(ATTATCHMENT_FILE_PATH);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(Global.ATTATCHMENT_FILE_NAME);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect();
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent Mail Successfully");
```

Comment: so what have you tried?   Did you wrap the code in a try/catch block?  Have you debugged through that section of the code?

Comment: Yeahhh, I did wrap it in try/catch block, as said it isn't throwing any exception, I have a scheduler to run my code,  it's directly jumping to                                                                                  catch (Throwable ex) {
                setException(ex);
                return false;                                                                   of FutureTask.class

Comment: So all the code above is inside some run() method somewhere that is getting trigger by your scheduler?  Might help to show more of that code because it sounds like the base code should work okay.